# Eigen internal parallelization

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, eigen

I'm programming a numerical simulation code for solving a N-equation system by means of matrix inversion techniques. I'm using the BiCGStab solver implemented in Eigen 3. It works fine, but no so fast as i expected so now i'm trying to activate multithreading, via OpenMP, simply compiling on GCC with the flag "-fopenmp". Then, i set the number of threads in shell by "export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4; ./app_name". The thing is that only one core is running in the system monitor and the computation time i the same, so i guess that i'm missing something.

Any ideas?

I'm running Linux Debian 6 64-bit, GCC 4.4.

Thanks!!

Comment: Last I checked Eigen only uses OpenMP for certain calculations such as large dense matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

(Update)

Nowadays (Eigen 3.3.4), the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) reads as:

> Currently, the following algorithms can make use of multi-threading:
>
> general dense matrix - matrix products
>
> PartialPivLU
>
> row-major-sparse * dense vector/matrix products
>
> ConjugateGradient with Lower|Upper as the UpLo template parameter.
>
> **BiCGSTAB with a row-major sparse matrix format.**
>
> LeastSquaresConjugateGradient

Answer (score 1):

According to the Eigen documentation site (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html):

> Currently, the following algorithms can make use of multi-threading: general matrix - matrix products PartialPivLU

So no support for BiCGStab yet, unfortunately (except for maybe any matrix multiplications done internally)